# Flex 4 NavigatorContent Inherited creationPolicy set to none

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

In Flex 4 in a TabNavigator container if the TN creationPolicy is auto, which it
is by default, then the creationPolicy of any NavigatorContent containers in the
TN will be none.

Two questions:

1) What are the implications of NavigatorContent creationPolicy being none in
this case, because its children still get created.

2) Why does it inherit a policy of none if the TN has one of auto? I saw how
this is done in NavigatorContent.as, but why?

Answer (score 0):

The creation policy of the NavigatorContent container is based on the creation policy of its parent navigator container.

please refer the [language reference for NavigatorContent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/NavigatorContent.html)

Comment: Sorry,i haven't answered your question.  i also did some testing, the result doesn't follow the description of adobe docs. very confusing.